# tkinter labelframe class inheritance issue

Tags: tkinter

I've created a simple class that inherits from tkinter's LabelFrame  However, when I run the code there is no LabelFrame appear. How do I fix this inheritance issue?

```
import tkinter as tk

class LabelFrame1(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, master, *default_geometry):

        super().__init__(master)

        self.master = master
        self.text = "试件大小"
        self.width, self.height = default_geometry
        self.pack()


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    LabelFrame1(root, 100, 200)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell python to set width and height of `tk.LabelFrame`. It is 0,0 for width, height:

```
self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
```

Now you will see the frame.

---

Also, `self.text` will simply assign the string to `self.text`. TO display the text on the window, do:

```
tk.Label(self,text=self.text).pack()
```

Comment: It is done.  However, i am still confuse that with inheritance from LabelFrame, can not the new (child) class inheritate all the attributes from master class automatically (since I have used the super().__init__(master)).